# How do I call an external function in C++?

Tags: c++, function

I have two files, payroll.cpp and pay.cpp, and in pay.cpp I have the function "calculatepay" and I want to call it in payroll.cpp, I am fairly new to C++ and have little to no real experience with it. All tips and help is appreciated in advance!

Payroll.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
  {
/*
B C and G MUST BE EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "pay.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main ()
  {
    char name[256];
    double pay, rate, hours;
    string inscode;

    while (cin.get(name,21))
      {
        cin >> rate;
        cin >> hours;
        cin >> inscode;
        cin.ignore(2,'\n');

        cout << "|" << name << "|";
        cout << "|" << rate << "|";
        cout << "|" << hours << "|";
        cout << "|" << inscode << "|" << endl;

        pay = pay.calculatepay(rate, hours);

        cout << setw(7) << fixed << setprecision(2) << rate << endl;
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

pay.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double calculatePay(double rate, double hours){
 double overtime;
 double pay;
 if(hours > 40){
  overtime = hours - 40;
  pay = ((rate *2)*overtime)+(rate *(hours - overtime));
 }else{
  pay = rate * hours;
 }
 return pay;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `calculatePay()` is in the global namespace, simply call it from your main function. e.g.

```
pay = calculatePay(rate, hours);
```

Normally you wouldn't #include a cpp file, but the way you have it will work.
Typically you declare a function prototype in a header file: pay.h, and include that. This will keep the compiler happy when compiling payroll.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `#include` .cpp files from .cpp files. Instead, create a header file to hold the function definition for calculatePay:

```
//pay.h
double calculatePay(double rate, double hours);
```

Then, `#include` pay.h in payroll.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "pay.h"
```

Here are a few more things to note about your code:

```
pay = pay.calculatepay(rate, hours);
```

This won't work. `pay` is a double, a simple number. It has no `calculatePay` method. Your `calculatePay` method is freefloating:

```
pay = calculatePay(rate, hours);
```

You also have some duplicate code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
  {
/*
B C and G MUST BE EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS.
*/
```

You don't want this in your code. You only want *one* main. The extra `#include`s won't *hurt*, but they're not exactly the best of ideas for clean code, either.

Also, `using namespace std` is well-liked in academia, but generally frowned on in the real world. Using the `std` prefix (`std::`) is more widely accepted.

Comment: when ever I do your solution I get this error

payroll.cpp: In function âint main()â:
payroll.cpp:29:32: error: âcalculatepayâ was not declared in this scope

Comment: You need to `#include "pay.h"`. And check your spelling, `calculatepay` and `calculatePay` are different.

Comment: Thank you Matt McNabb, I did not notice that at all!

but now I'm getting these very interesting errors

/tmp/ccVB731x.o: In function `main':
payroll.cpp:(.text+0x171): undefined reference to `calculatePay(double, double)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It may be that I am using an older compiler on my schools servers

Comment: Your linker is giving you an error that it can't find the compiled definition of calculatePay. Make sure on your command line you have both `payroll.cpp` and `pay.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `pay.h`. Put the declaration of the function `calculatePay` in it. Include it in both `payroll.cpp` and `pay.cpp`.

**`pay.h`**

```
#ifndef PAY_H
#define PAY_H

extern double calculatePay(double rate, double hours);

#endif
```

**`pay.cpp` and `payroll.cpp`**

```
#include "pay.h"
// Then the rest of the file.
```

Comment: The `extern` keyword can safely be removed from the declaration in the header - the function has external linkage by default.